# Python Script for Sequence Numbers of PCAP File Using Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I am a (very) new python user and have successfully downloaded PIP, Scapy, and a few other packages in Linux. I am attempting to write a script to analyze a pcap file. My goal is to extract the sequence numbers of the UDP packets as well as timestamps and then analyze this info to find gaps/errors.

**How does one go about extracting UDP sequence numbers from the file?**

In the terminal, I defined: a = 'file.pcap' . I can then use some commands like hexdump(a). It is not clear what the output is telling me. For example, the last line of hexdump(a) is:

23d610 1B 5B 30 6D 1B 5B 30 6D 3E 1B 5B 30 6D 5D .[0m.[0m>.[0m]

Scapy is able to provide packet info for packet n by typing a[n] as well.

Comment: this is quite a vague question. you might consider breaking down your goal into small tasks (such as 'read the file in python', and then 'read a specific string in the file in python') and when you get stuck on one of those tasks, ask another more specific question

Comment: I will edit accordingly. Thank you for your suggestion!

Comment: @danyamachine I have taken out the first question since I would prefer to use Scapy. I am really wondering how to extract certain bits of data (sequence number/time) from the packets within the pcap file.

Comment: next question: what have you tried? what didn't work about what you tried? (if you haven't made any attempts to solve your problem yet, go try a few things ;) )

Comment: I'm simply trying to understand the format of UDP/pcap and extracting embedded info. The commands I have tried are listed in the post. I am currently trying to make sense of the a[n] command output. In particular, I see 4 layers: Ether, IP, UDP, RAW. Each layer contains some info, is the sequence number/time within this output?

Comment: it sounds like your question is about the structure of a pcap file, not about how to use python. you might consider reposting (with much more specificity) in the networing stackexchange, or doing some googling on pcap

Comment: I agree with posting a question regarding the PCAP file structure. However, is there a Scapy command for either of the two data I am interested in?

Comment: Have you read [this doc](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/demo.html). Among other it contains an example on `rdpcap` . It'll return all packets in the pcap as a list.

Comment: Yes, that's how I have defined my pcap file in the terminal (a=rdpcap("path")) and from there I can execute a[n] for some number n and see output.

Comment: Hi Joseph.  If you are specifically looking for a UDP sequence number I don't believe you will find it.  UDP is considered connectionless and does not have a sequence number.  TCP does though.  Here is a good reference for [UDP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol).